# Regex-Groups in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem using a Javascript-Regexp.

**This is a very simplified regexp, which demonstrates my Problem:**

```
(?:\s(\+\d\w*))|(\w+)
```

This regex should only match strings, that doesn't contain forbidden characters (everything that is no word-character).

The only exception is the Symbol `+`
A match is allowed to start with this symbol, if `[0-9]` is trailing. 
And a `+` must not appear within words (`44+44` is not a valid match, but `+4ad` is)

In order to allow the + only at the beginning, I said that there must be a whitespace preceding. However, I don't want the whitespace to be part of the match.

I tested my regex with this tool: http://regex101.com/#javascript and the resultig matches look fine.

**There are 2 Issues with that regexp:**

- If I use it in my JS-Code, the space is always part of the match
- If `+42` appears at the beginning of a line, it won't be matched

**My Questions:**

- How should the regex look like?
- Why does this regex add the space to the matches?

**Here's my JS-Code:**

```
var input =  "+5ad6  +5ad6 sd asd+as +we";
var regexp = /(?:\s(\+\d\w*))|(\w+)/g;
var tokens = input.match(regexp);
console.log(tokens);
```

Comment: The space: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505762/regex-non-capturing-groups-in-javascript -- using a non-capturing group does not exclude it from the *total* match, only from adding it to individual matching *groups*.

Comment: @Jongware so is there a way to extract the token without the space? Unfortunately, JS doesn't support lookbehinds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should the regex look like?

You've got multiple choices to reach your goal:

- It's fine as you have it. You might allow the [string beginning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) in place of the whitespace as well, though. Just get the capturing groups (`tokens[1]`, `tokens[2]`) out of it, which will not include the whitespace.
- If you didn't use JavaScript, a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) could help. Unfortunately it's not supported.
- Require a non-[word-boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) before the `+`, which would make every `\w` character before the `+` prevent the match:

  ```
  /\B\+\d\w+|\w+/
  ```

> Why does this regex add the space to the matches?

Because the regex does match the whitespace. It does not add the `\s(\+\d\w+)` to the [*captured groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), though.

Comment: The regex can even be improved: `(\B\+\d)?\w+`

Comment: Yes, or `(?:\B\+\d)?\w+`. I just tried not to make a large change to the original expression.

Comment: I take it back - this simplification doesn't work, because it would force tokens starting with a `+` to have at least 2 characters afterwards

Comment: But doesn't the original expression do the same? Or did you mean `\+\d\w*`

Comment: Yes, I meant `\+\d\w*`

Comment: Then you could use lookahead: `(?:\B\+(?=\d))?\w+?`

Comment: unfortunately lookahead and lookbehind aren't supported in JavaScript. But the current solution works fine