# Need help in formatting JSON (in JavaScript) with Stringify and Regex replace

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I am missing something with the regex and it's removing the last letter of each item before the comma.

Sample code:

```
let test_json = { 
    "a" : { "a1" : "one", "is_active" : true, "a2" : "two" },
    "b" : { "b1" : "one", "is_active" : true, "b2" : "two" } 
}; 

JSON.stringify(test_json, null, 3).replace(/[^}],\n( )*"/g, ',   "');
```

The result is:

```
"{
   "a": {
      "a1": "one,   "is_active": tru,   "a2": "two"
   },
   "b": {
      "b1": "one,   "is_active": tru,   "b2": "two"
   }
}"
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
"{
   "a": {
      "a1": "one",   "is_active": true,   "a2": "two"
   },
   "b": {
      "b1": "one",   "is_active": true,   "b2": "two"
   }
}"
```

The things that are wrong:
"one,     should be     "one",
"tru,     should be     "true",

Comment: "Text that's matched inside a non-capturing group is still consumed, the same as text that's matched outside of any group. A capturing group is like a non-capturing group with extra functionality: in addition to grouping, it allows you to extract whatever it matches independently of the overall match." - From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505762/regex-non-capturing-groups-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are finding the following sequence of characters

- Any character that is not a closing brace
- A comma
- A newline character
- Any number of spaces

And replacing *the entire sequence*. Since the "e" on the end of "true" is not a closing brace, it gets replaced as well.

What you need is for the first item in the sequence to be "a comma that comes immediately after a closing brace". You can do this using a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```js
let test_json = {
  a: {
    a1: "one",
    is_active: true,
    a2: "two"
  },
  b: {
    b1: "one",
    is_active: true,
    b2: "two"
  },
};

const result = JSON.stringify(test_json, null, 3).replace(
  /(?<!}),\n\s*/g,
  ", "
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.stringify(test_json,null,3).replace(/([^}]?),\n( )*"/g, '$1,   "');
```

not sure of it's the best way but it's the first thing that came to mind

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for me as it messes up the formatting for "b", which should come on a new line